# Update column of an existing table with a dataframe column using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a table in backend (sql server)

```
table1
id   column1 column2
xxx   sada    NULL
yyy   dasa    NULL
zzz   awas    NULL
```

I have a dataframe - `result_df`  - column -  `result_df.column2` , and want to update the table , but its not working

```
session.query(table1).filter(table1.Id == result_df.id).update({table1.column2: result_df.column2})
```

but its not working , is there a better way to do this

am using sqlalchemy and python

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful documentation here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes

In order to update every row according to the dataframe, we need to use [bindparam](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) with a list of dictionaries specifying each value.

I transformed the dataframe with `to_dict('records')` and as *'id' is reserved for automatic usage in the VALUES*, I transformed the `id` column into `_id`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import bindparam

params = [{'_id' if k[0] == 'id' else k[0]: k[1]
           for k in d.items()} for d in df.to_dict('records')]

stmt = table1.update() \
    .where(table1.c.id == bindparam('_id')) \
    .values(column2=bindparam('column2'))
con.execute(stmt, params)
```

The complete working example: https://ideone.com/3TQmZ7

Another more explicit example from the documentation:

```py
stmt = (users_table.update().
        where(user_table.c.name == bindparam('username')).
        values(fullname=bindparam('fullname'))
        )

connection.execute(
    stmt, [{"username": "wendy", "fullname": "Wendy Smith"},
           {"username": "jack", "fullname": "Jack Jones"},
           ]
)
```